# HTML Scrolling Box

Tags: html, window, scroll

I am trying to create a box that will scroll with you as you move down or up a page.

An example would www.npr.org 's top bar that moves with the scrolling.

I just need an example of how to accomplish this. I haven't touched HTML in a while so I'm rusty.

Thanks.

Comment: PHP won't do this - it's a server-side system. You need to be looking at client-side technologies. Note that asking for product recommendations is off-topic for [so]. I'm sure Google can help.

Comment: I made a mistake. I meant to put HTML, not PHP.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you can use:

position:fixed;

in a css style. Is that what you were trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can achieve this with doing smth similar to this:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {              
   if($(document).scrollTop() > 50){ 
      $('#myDiv').addClass('positionFixed')
   }else{
     $('#myDiv').removeClass('positionFixed');
   }
});
```

Comment: I have this in my css class, how do I call it from my HTML file?